# Wordpress embed pdf automatically after upload via media

Tags: wordpress, pdf, upload, embed

I want to upload pdf files via media->add new which should be automatically embedded to a unique page for displaying it. So that I can just give that page link to my client to view the uploaded pdf.

Please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure what you mean by "embedded to a unique page"
But when you upload a file in Wordpress, it gives you the direct URL to the uploaded file in many locations .

You can simply give that URL to anyone you desire.

[image: Add media screen]

and also in the Edit Media screen [image]

As well in other places as well - > But I think you get the point .